# How to rename an object in Google Storage bucket?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

How to rename an object in Google Storage bucket through the API?

See also [An error attempting to rename a Google Bucket object (Google bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45887797/856090)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects can't be renamed. The best you can do is copy to a new object and delete the original. If the new and old object are the same location (which will be true if they're in the same bucket, for example) it will be a metadata-only (no byte copying) operation, and hence fast. However, since it's two operations it won't be atomic.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you want to do this programmatically or manually, but the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool has a [mv](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) option which can be used for renaming objects.

```
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/oldprefix gs://my_bucket/newprefix
```

As other posters noted, behind the scenes, this does a copy and delete.

Comment: I take it this copy-delete method does not transfer the creation date of the original object to the new location?

Answer (score 2):

First, use the "rewrite" method to produce a copy of the original object. Then, delete the original object.

Documentation on rewrite: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite